# Confusing behavior of `Ctrl-]` in vim documentation navigation

Tags: vim

Vim documentation `usr_01` says:

`Press  CTRL-]  to jump to a subject under the cursor`

The help docs have `help` filetype and support `|link|` to `*link*` type of links. Confusingly, these are also seem to be navigable by <kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd>.

Problem I have is when such a `|link|` is also in a tagfile. If it is, then <kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd> takes me to the tagfile definition, and not the `*link*` location.

For a real example, see `filetype.txt` helpfile in standard Vim. It has this entry:

```
3. Docs for the default filetype plugins.   |ftplugin-docs|
```

Now, if you place cursor at `ftplugin-docs` on the first part of the word and hit <kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd>, you will be taken to tags definition for `ftplugin` which is in `usr_41` file's line 2101:

```
41.12   Writing a filetype plugin       *write-filetype-plugin* *ftplugin*
```

How do I jump instead to the line 395 in `filetypes.txt` file? which is:

```
3.  docs for the default filetype plugins.              *ftplugin-docs*
```

Comment: A bit of fiddling with visual mode suggests that the problem is with "word" vs "WORD" objects. Visually selecting `|ftplugin-docs|` and then hitting <kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd> actually takes me to the `*ftplugin-docs*` line. But surely there should be some other more efficient way.

Comment: I don't see what you're describing in gVim 7.4 on Windows. In fact, I get exactly the behavior that you seem to be desiring.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang Do you see the problem behaviour (jump to line 2101) or the desired jump (to line 395) ?

Comment: Mine jumps to 395, on Windows (7.4), Android (VimTouch, 7.3), and MacVim (7.4).